# Einsum matrix multiplication with missing dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy-einsum

I want to modify this einsum to be more flexible. Right now it's doing a matrix multiplication of the last two dimensions of A against the last 3 of B:

```
tf.einsum("...xp,...pyz->...xyz", A, B)
```

However I want it to be able to handle *any* number of dimensions after `p` in B. If it helps, I do know the `pivot_axis` of `p` (i.e. the position in `tf.shape(B)`).

I suppose one way to do it would be to get the number of dimensions after p and do some string trick like:

```
suffix='abcdefghijklmno'[:len(tf.shape(B))-pivot_axis]
tf.einsum(f"...xp,...p{suffix}->...x{suffix}", A, B)
```

and append it to the einsum strings? Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Einsum will to be the fastest way to do this. It can do done using matmul, but it requires reshaping inputs and outputs.